# Is there a way to check for compile flags that doesn't require the autoconf-archive package?

Tags: gcc, configure, autoconf, automake, m4

The `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` macro is available in most distributions in the `autoconf-archive` package, but unfortunately when missing that package the error is impossible to understand:

`./configure: 5358: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

This is the configure.ac line that causes the error:

`AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-fcx-fortran-rules, CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fcx-fortran-rules")`

Is there a way to check if a compile flag works without using an AX_ check?

Should I just copy-paste this AX_ check into my configure.ac?  That seems like a bit of a hack, but it would work...is there something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the prudent thing to do when using any macro which does not come with autoconf or automake is to add a line to `configure.ac` which will check that the generated `configure` file does not contain the name of the macro (only its expansion which should not contain the macro name):

```
m4_pattern_forbid([AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG])dnl
```

This will make `autoreconf` fail and produce a halfway decent error message instead of silently generating an invalid `configure` from `configure.ac` when the `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` macro definition cannot be found.

Then you can copy the `*.m4` file containing the definition of `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` into your project's source tree (e.g. into a `m4/` subdirectory) and then add a line to the top-level `Makefile.am` which tells `aclocal` where to look for macro definitions:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

In addition to that, you need to add the `m4/whatever-the-name-is.m4` file to `EXTRA_DIST` in some `Makefile.am` or Makefile include file so that it becomes possible to run `autoreconf` on an unpacked dist tarball.

I personally prefer to use `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([auto-m4])` in `configure.ac` and `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I auto-m4 -I project-m4` in the top-level `Makefile.am` to separate `*.m4` files of different origin into different directories in my source tree (`auto-m4/` for the `*.m4` files copied there during `autoreconf` runs, and `project-m4/` for the `*.m4` files I have written myself for the project).

Note that while `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([...])` exists to help with multiple m4 macro directories and avoids the necessity for the above ACLOCAL_AMFLAG line, `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS` only works with autoconf and automake. As soon as your build system also uses libtool/libtoolize or gettext/gettextize/autopoint, they will fail upon encountering `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS`. So stay with `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` and `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS`.